# CSR creation for Azure Website

Tags: ssl, csr, azure-web-apps

I have hosted an ASp.net core web application as an Azure Website. Since you cannot do a remote desktop connection and create a CSR file, Im at a loss as to how to create one for this file.

As mentioned here

[Must CSRs be generated on the server that will host the SSL certificate?](https://serverfault.com/questions/471289/must-csrs-be-generated-on-the-server-that-will-host-the-ssl-certificate)"

But where are the private keys and public keys mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use solution from [this article](https://docs.druva.com/Knowledge_Base/inSync/How_To/Using_Microsoft_IIS_to_generate_CSR_and_Private_Key).

Also, you could use `openssl` to generate CSR. You'll generate private key and CSR with two commands. For example you could check [this article](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1221018-generate-csr---openssl).

OpenSSL for Windows could be downloaded from [here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).